# Function to Print Out Averages

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix

I'm trying to print out the averages in the function `void printavg(float *matrix,float *rowAve,float *colAve, float overallAve, int rows, int cols);`
but when I tried to do a test run on printing out the average for rows I didn't get the right answer. What's the proper way to print out the avg using the `printavg` function. Here's an example of what the program should do:

```
Enter row dimension <must be between 1 and 5>: 3
Enter column dimension <must be between 1 and 5>: 2
Enter 6 data values for 3 x 2 matrix, in by-row order
1
2
3
4
5
6
1.00 2.00   1.50
3.00 4.00   3.50
5.00 6.00   5.50

3.00 4.00
Overall average is: 3.500000
Enter 0 to continue with a new matrix
Enter any other number to terminate the program:
```

Here's the code that I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 // Function Prototypes
 float *readMatrix(int rows, int cols);
 float *rowavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols);
 float *colavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols);
 float overallavg(float* matrix, int rows, int cols);
 void printavg(float *matrix, float *rowAve, float *colAve, float overallAve, int rows, int cols);

 #define MAX_DIM 15

int main(void)
{
  int done = 0;
  int rows, cols;
  float *dataMatrix;
  float *rowAveVector;
  float *colAveVector;
  float overallAve;

  while (!done)
  {
    // Prompt user to enter row and column dimensions of matrix (must be > 0)
    do
    {
        printf("Enter row dimension (must be between 1 and %d): ", MAX_DIM);
        scanf("%d", &rows);    
    } while(rows <= 0 || rows > MAX_DIM);
    do
    {
        printf("Enter column dimension (must be between 1 and %d): ", MAX_DIM);
        scanf("%d", &cols);
    } while(cols <= 0 || cols > MAX_DIM);

    dataMatrix = readMatrix(rows, cols);
    if (dataMatrix == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Program terminated due to dynamic memory allocation failure\n");
        return (0);
    }

    rowAveVector = rowavg(dataMatrix, rows, cols);
    colAveVector = colavg(dataMatrix, rows, cols);
    if(rowAveVector == NULL || colAveVector == NULL)
    {
     printf("malloc failed.  Terminating program\n");
     return (0);
    }
    overallAve = overallavg(dataMatrix, rows, cols);

    //Print Averages
    printAverages(dataMatrix, rowAveVector, colAveVector, overallAve, rows, cols);

    free(dataMatrix);
    free(rowAveVector);
    free(colAveVector);

    //Check if user wants to enter a new matrix
    printf("Enter 0 to continue with a new matrix\n");
    printf("Enter any other number to terminate the program: ");
    scanf("%d", &done);
  }
  //That's it, we are done
  return (0);
}

float *readMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int elements=0;
    float *m=malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(float));

    if (m==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            elements = i*cols+j;
            scanf("%f", &m[elements]);
        }
    }
    return m;
}

float *rowavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols)
{

  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  float mean=0;
  float *Average_array=malloc(rows*sizeof(float));
  if (Average_array==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
      {
          mean+=matrix[i*cols+j];
      }
      Average_array[i]=(float)(mean/cols);
  }
  return Average_array;
}

float *colavg(float *matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  if (matrix==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  float mean=0;
  float *Average_array=malloc(cols*sizeof(float));
  if (Average_array==NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for (i=0;i<cols;i++)
  {
      for (j=0;j<rows;j++)
      {
          mean+=matrix[j*cols+i];
      }
      Average_array[i]=(float)(mean/rows);
  }
  return Average_array;
}

float overallavg(float* matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    float sum=0;
    int i=0;
    float elements=0;
    float mean;
    elements=rows*cols;
    for (i=0;i<elements;i++)
    {
        sum+=matrix[i];
    }
    mean=sum/elements;
    return mean;
}

void printavg(float *matrix, float *rowAve, float *colAve, float overallAve, int rows, int cols)
{
  printf("%f",rowAve[rows,cols]);
}
```

Comment: "when i tired to do a test run on printing out the average for rows I didn't get the right answer", .  What did you get?

Comment: I never ran the overall average but when i ran to get the averages for each row i got 10.5000

Comment: Have a look at `rowAve[rows, cols]`  It does the same as `rowAve[cols]`

Comment: I got `10.5` too but only after correcting the function name that does not compile.

Comment: On from @chux, `rowAve[cols]` will out of the array bounds.

Comment: You need to test the return value from `scanf()`.  If the user types `a` instead of `3` for the number of rows, your program is going to run for a long time.  Also, why on earth are you returning allocated `float *` for the single numeric values from `rowavg()` and `colavg()`?  It would be much, much, much more sensible simply to return the `float` value.  And you'd pass simple `float` values to the `printAverages()` function too.  And you wouldn't need to free the returned pointers.

Comment: http://ideone.com/CY1wRg